# How to use the files().update method in Google Drive Python API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm using the [Google Drive Python API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads?hl=en_US#multipart), and I'm having trouble updating a file on Drive.

Here is my code for updating a file. The code runs without any errors, and even returns the correct file ID at the end, but it does not update the file on Drive.

```
basename = "myfile.txt"
filename = "/path/to/myfile.txt"
file_metadata = {'name': basename}
media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().update(fileId=file_id, body=file_metadata, media_body=media).execute()
print(file)
```

The print(file) statement produces the following output:

```
{'id': <fileid>}
```

What's curious is that I'm able to create a file without any issues. Here is my code for creating a file, which creates a file successfully.

```
basename = "myfile.txt"
filename = "/path/to/myfile.txt"
file_metadata = {'name': basename, 'parents': [drive_folder_id]}
media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='text/plain')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

Why am I able to create a file, but not update a file?

How can I improve my code for updating a file so that it successfully updates the file on Drive?

**Summary:**

My code for updating a file runs smoothly, but it doesn't do the thing it's intended to do, that is, update the contents of the file. How can I update the contents of a file on Drive using the Google Drive Python API v3?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error message? If so, include it in your question please. Also, what exactly are you updating that is not working?

Comment: @YancyGodoy I'm updating the content of a file. I'm not getting any error messages. I include the file contents in the media_body=media argument.

Comment: have you tried using the wrapper? https://github.com/technicalheist/gdrivepy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite a file using Google Drive API with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408552/how-to-overwrite-a-file-using-google-drive-api-with-python)

Comment: @YancyGodoy I tried that suggestion (from your link) and it didn't work. It's a lot like the code I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the body parameter should point to a file resource object, not a plain dictionary as in your code. See this example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#python)

```
try:
    # First retrieve the file from the API.
    file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

    # File's new metadata.
    file['title'] = new_title
    file['description'] = new_description
    file['mimeType'] = new_mime_type

    # File's new content.
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(
        new_filename, mimetype=new_mime_type, resumable=True)

    # Send the request to the API.
    updated_file = service.files().update(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=file,
        newRevision=new_revision,
        media_body=media_body).execute()
    return updated_file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
    return None
```

Comment: You're referring to documentation for v2 of the API. Is this true for v3?

Comment: Hm, they do not provide an example at v3, but you might be right that they changed the behavior as they switched from HTTP method PUT to PATCH, so you might no longer need the complete file object...however, did you try the code in the example?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may have been my web browser's caching feature. I was looking at files that I updated and I didn't see any changes, and this may have been caused by caching.

I switched browsers and tested, and it seems to be the case.

The `update` method works for me now.